# Switch functionality in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

While using case statement whose syntax is

```
      case $variable-name  in

            pattern1)  command;;

            patternN)  command;;

            *)         command;;
       esac
```

Here " *)" is meant for default case whose patterns doesn’t match for any case. What if I want to match for the pattern " * "  and do multiplication and should have default case also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either escape the `*` character using `\*` or if you are doing certain operations such as addition, multiplication, etc. based on the choice of pattern/character it is better to use numbers to indicate the operation. For example:

1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division

So by doing this your case statement can be something like this:

```
case $variable-name in
    1)sum=$((n1 + $n2))
     echo "Sum = $sum";;
    2)difference=$((n1 - n2))
     echo "Sub = $difference";;
    3)product=$(( n1 * n2 ))
     echo "Mul = $product";;
    4)quotient=$(( n1 / n2 ))
     echo "Div = $quotient";;
    *)echo "Invalid choice";;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

Just escape it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

variable-name="*"

case $variable-name in
    \*) echo "Star";;
    *) echo "Default";;
esac
```

Or you could put the * in quotes.